# InDesign table cell background yellow in Normal view mode

Tags: adobe-indesign

An InDesign doc has a table, with one column has some cells with a light-yellow background in Normal view mode (where the outlines are visible).

[image]

If I move to Preview mode (where the outlines are invisible), the light-yellow background goes back to the correctly styled colour.

Why do I see a light yellow-background for some cells and not others in Normal mode?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text in those cells have a tab setting with an [Align On ...](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/tabs-indents.html#specify_characters_for_decimal_tabs) for its decimals, but applying that tab would move the text out of the cell at its right – there is no room to align. Hence the warning.

If you don't mind the mis-alignment, you can safely ignore the yellow marks, as they indeed do not show up in Preview and in exported PDFs.

You can fix it if you want, by selecting all numeric cells in each column and adjust that Align On tab using the tab ruler.

Comment: This answer is correct, the yellow is not part of the table formatting, the cells are plain white. In this particular case the yellow is a UI highlight to show a font "problem" (a few other situations exist where these highlights are shown).